Is there a way to remove select rights on a database to sysadmins?
I have a tiny database with very specific compliance requirements. Our legal team wants us to limit read access to that database to specific group of people. The problem is that they do not want most of our DBAs to have access to it, and at the same time I am trying to avoid putting that DB on a dedicated instance.
I wander if it is possible to put such database on the SQL instance where there is an AD group for DBAs with sysadmin rights and restrict select rights on a database level in the way that only one of DBAs would be able to see data.
... my current understanding is that it is not possible, but I thought that it is worth to double-check.

This question is similar to: How to prevent sysadmin server role from executing a stored procedure. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is not possible.
Member of the sysadmin group (sa) have full right on every objects in the instance (including database tables).
As the "deny" doesn't apply to "sa" members, there is no way to prevent a DBA from being able to read the data in this table.
If there is some kind of sensible data that DBA should not have access to, then you may want to look at encryption (Always Encrypted for example).

Another a solution would be setting up auditing and have another a team to review who's been working on the restricted database. This won't prevent a rougue admin from restoring a backup of said DB to a non-auditing insance and thus cirucmventing the audit.
